# Pandas Groupby: Count and mean combined

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Working with pandas to try and summarise a data frame as a count of certain categories, as well as the means sentiment score for these categories.

There is a table full of strings that have different sentiment scores, and I want to group each text source by saying how many posts they have, as well as the average sentiment of these posts.

My (simplified) data frame looks like this:

```
source    text              sent
--------------------------------
bar       some string       0.13
foo       alt string        -0.8
bar       another str       0.7
foo       some text         -0.2
foo       more text         -0.5
```

The output from this should be something like this:

```
source    count     mean_sent
-----------------------------
foo       3         -0.5
bar       2         0.415
```

The answer is somewhere along the lines of:

```
df['sent'].groupby(df['source']).mean()
```

Yet only gives each source and it's mean, with no column headers.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.groupby('source') \
       .agg({'text':'size', 'sent':'mean'}) \
       .rename(columns={'text':'count','sent':'mean_sent'}) \
       .reset_index()
print (df)
  source  count  mean_sent
0    bar      2      0.415
1    foo      3     -0.500
```

Comment: great answer. How would you do this if you wanted to the count and mean of the same column? Cause you'll get a duplicate key error if you pass in the column name twice.

Comment: @Yu Chen sure, use `df1 = (df.groupby('source')['your column']
       .agg(('count', 'size') , ('avg', 'mean')) 
       .reset_index())`

Comment: I have several variables I want a mean of in my dataset, and I only want a count of the variable I am grouping by. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 32):

In newer versions of pandas you don't need the rename anymore, just use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df = df.groupby('source') \
       .agg(count=('text', 'size'), mean_sent=('sent', 'mean')) \
       .reset_index()

print (df)
  source  count  mean_sent
0    bar      2      0.415
1    foo      3     -0.500
```

Comment: I have several variables I want a mean of in my dataset, and I only want a count of the variable I am grouping by. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa you will probably need to build a dictionary of key: (tuple) and pass it using **kdict. Probably your code will be clearer if you this twice.

Comment: @JodeCharger100 you can use `groupby.transform` with the size argument to get the count before you call `groupby.mean`:
`df['size'] = df.groupby('group_var').transform('size')
    mean_df = df.groupby('group_var').mean()`

Answer (score 16):

Below one should work fine:

```
df[['source','sent']].groupby('source').agg(['count','mean'])
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version to achieve this is:

```
df.groupby('source')['sent'].agg(count='size', mean_sent='mean').reset_index()
```

The nice thing about this is that you can extend it if you want to take the mean of multiple variables but only count once. In this case you will have to pass a dictionary:

```
df.groupby('source')['sent1', 'sent2'].agg({'count': 'size', 'means': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who were looking for aggregations for more than two columns (as I were): just add those to 'agg'.

```
df = df.groupby(['id']).agg({'texts': 'size', 'char_num': 'mean', 'bytes': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should provide the output that you wanted:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('source').size())

results['mean_score'] =  df.groupby('source').sent.mean()
```