# How to calculate the average of a column where the row meets a certain condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average

Basically I have this Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'number': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6], 'time':[34,33,41,36,43,22,24,32,29,28,33,32,55,51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

[image: Pandas dataframe]

And I want to transform the `df` or create another one where instead of being several rows with the same `'number'`, there is a unique `'number'` per row; and in the `'time'` column, its average (of the records that had the same `'number'`). Also, there should be a 3rd column called `'count'` that shows the amount of records each `'number'` had.

The output expected is:

[image: Pandas dataframe 2]

Thanks.

Comment: `new_df = df.groupby('number', as_index=False).agg(count=('time', 'count'), time=('time', 'mean'))` ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424436/15497888) or equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `groupby` + `agg`:

```
agg = df.groupby('number')['time'].agg(['count', 'mean']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> agg
   number  count  mean
0       1      5  37.4
1       2      3  26.0
2       4      4  30.5
3       6      2  53.0
```